# Does method writeFile work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, dropbox

I am writing Dropbox web-application and use Client Library for the Dropbox:
https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js.
For uploading file choosen by user I use method writeFile. Html object File(< input type=file >) is passed as parameter data. It works fine in FireFox.
It is said that this library is tested against IE9 and IE10.

Does method writeFile work in IE8?

If it does not work in IE8 then is there way to use html form for uploading file to dropbox?

Dropbox docs does not give example how to upload file by html form.
Is there some example?

Answer (score 2):

`writeFile` takes the contents of the file, not an HTML `input` tag. See http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/classes/Dropbox/Client.html#writeFile-instance.

This means your JavaScript has to have access to the actual contents of the file to use `writeFile`. The HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) might help here, but it certainly doesn't work in IE8.

I think this means you'll need to upload the file to your own servers (via a standard form submit) and then transfer the file from there to Dropbox.

**EDIT**: Remove a clause claiming general poor support for File API. It looks like it's not that bad: http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api

Comment: Good answer, but I just wanted to add that all browsers other than IE9 and older have complete file API support.